# Visual force page failed to show up in EU6 orgs in Lightning

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Visualforce page failed to show up in EU6 orgs when installed via managed package.

> This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app.

Steps to reproduce

1. Create a Visual Force page and enable it for both Salesforce1 and Lightning with `standardcontroller="opportunity"`
2. Install the package in another EU6 org. And drop this visual force page inside opportunity layout.
3. View any opportunity in Salesforce Lightning. The Visual Force page will give following error.

   > This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app.

Please note this is happening in orgs which are in EU6 reason and only happening in lightening. On classic it is working fine. On Orgs other then EU6 it is working on both classic and lightening.

I already raises a case with Salesforce support, they are working on it.

Comment: the developer of that managed package has chosen not to enable it for lightning. Reach out to the developer and see if they have a lightning version

Comment: I have mentioned that in first step that is is enabled for lightening. And it works in lightening inside development org. Even this works in orgs others then EU6

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: @KaushikRay Hi, there is no fix. i have connected to salesforce support and after few weeks they found out it is salesforce internal issue. it is there in knows issues list, but if you raise a ticket then there tier 3 support will run a script from backend and fix it for the provided org id. it can be seen at link https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=when-managed-package-vf-pages-are-opened-even-though-cruc-is-enabled-instance-name-is-still-visible-in-the-url&Id=a1p3A0000003US1